# in R: Two Way Match to Matrix

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(DEP=letters[1:5], ARR=letters[11:15], NO=1:5+5)

   DEP ARR  NO
1   a   k   6
2   b   l   7
3   c   m   8
4   d   n   9
5   e   o  10
```

I want to create a matrix of DEP as ROW ID, and ARR as COL ID, and fill in the matrix with the relevant matching NO...

e.g.

```
  k l m n o
a 6 7 8 9 10 ...etc
```

Each combination is unique.

DEP and ARR are the same vector of names. I have chosen two different sample ones here for clarity.

I am struggling to use match to sort them and fill them into the matrix template I created below:

```
mat <- matrix(0,nrow(df),nrow(df)); colnames(mat) <- df$ARR; rownames(mat) <- df$DEP;

  k l m n o
a 0 0 0 0 0
b 0 0 0 0 0
c 0 0 0 0 0
d 0 0 0 0 0
e 0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this? Many thanks for all advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?xtabs`:

```
xtabs(NO ~ ., data=df)
#   ARR
#DEP  k  l  m  n  o
#  a  6  0  0  0  0
#  b  0  7  0  0  0
#  c  0  0  8  0  0
#  d  0  0  0  9  0
#  e  0  0  0  0 10
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you could use a sparse matrix definition:

```
library(Matrix)
mat <- spMatrix(length(df$DEP), length(df$ARR), 
                seq(df$DEP), seq(df$ARR), as.numeric(as.character(df$NO)))
rownames(mat) <- df$DEP
colnames(mat) <- df$ARR
#> as.matrix(mat)
#  k l m n  o
#a 6 0 0 0  0
#b 0 7 0 0  0
#c 0 0 8 0  0
#d 0 0 0 9  0
#e 0 0 0 0 10
```

Comment: It may well make the most sense to use a sparse matrix if there will be a lot of `0`'s

Comment: Many thanks! Trying out the sparse matrix. I have an error: invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: all column indices (slot 'j') must be between 0 and ncol-1 in a TsparseMatrix. Trying to sort it out.

Comment: the class is a factor. I've tried converting it with the same error. What do you recommend?

Comment: Thanks! I think we are missing a bracket in the mat <- or have one extra? The error I get is : .M.kind(x) : not yet implemented for matrix with typeof integer when I remove one of the double bracket after df$ARR...

Comment: This error suggests that `df$NO` is stored as a factor class. To resolve this, we can wrap `df$NO` into `as.numeric(as.character())` (see edit). Hope this helps.