# R - Create matrix from 3 raw vector

Tags: r, matrix

I have 3 vectors as the following:

```
A <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
B <- c("1/1/1", "1/1/1", "2/1/1", "2/1/1", "3/1/1")
C <- c(1, 1, -1, 1, -1)
```

and I want to create a matrix like the following using these 3 vectors:

```
- 1/1/1 2/1/1 3/1/1
A   1    0     0
B   1    0     0
C   0    -1    0
D   0    1     0
E   0    0     -1
```

where vector `A` and `B` are rows and columns respectively and I have the data as `C`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Very close to a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739840/in-r-two-way-match-to-matrix/37739993

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
`[<-`(array(0,c(length(unique(A)),length(unique(B))),
      list(unique(A),unique(B))),
       cbind(A,B),C)
#  1/1/1 2/1/1 3/1/1
#A     1     0     0
#B     1     0     0
#C     0    -1     0
#D     0     1     0
#E     0     0    -1
```

Comment: You may think of `'[<-'(A, cbind(i, j), C)` as `A[cbind(i, j)] <- C`

Answer (score 6):

Use `?xtabs`

```
xtabs(C ~ A+B)
#   B
#A   1/1/1 2/1/1 3/1/1
#  A     1     0     0
#  B     1     0     0
#  C     0    -1     0
#  D     0     1     0
#  E     0     0    -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `acast` from `reshape2` after creating a `data.frame`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(data.frame(A, B, C), A~B, value.var = "C", fill =0)
#  1/1/1 2/1/1 3/1/1
#A     1     0     0
#B     1     0     0
#C     0    -1     0
#D     0     1     0
#E     0     0    -1
```