# How to create a matrix with specified row and col names, from a dataframe containing the data and the names

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

If I have a dataframe like so:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2018/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 5),
                        ID1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                        ID2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

> dataframe
        Date ID1 ID2
1 2018-01-01   1   6
2 2018-01-02   2   7
3 2018-01-03   3   8
4 2018-01-04   4   9
5 2018-01-05   5  10
```

What is the best way to convert it into a matrix, with the observations as the data,  Dates as row names, and the IDs as col names?

I'd think there would be a function that converted dataframes and took certain column/rows as arguments for col/row names, but I have not found that.

Bonus question: Do I need to have a distinct matrix for each ID? Do I need to create a 3D array or similar? How could I do that?

Comment: Why do you need this as a matrix?

Comment: `row.names(dataframe) = dataframe$Date; dataframe = as.matrix(dataframe[,-1])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in R: Two Way Match to Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739840/in-r-two-way-match-to-matrix)

Comment: G5W's solution above works perfectly. Basically, I just needed to assign rownames based the Date column and then convert the appropriate index of the df into a matrix. The column names are taken are of automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the row names and then convert it to matrix:

```
as.matrix(data.frame(dataframe[-1], row.names = dataframe$Date))
```

Another possibility is to use a zoo or xts object.  This will create a matrix for the data and define an index attribute for the dates.  The resulting object is of class `zoo` and can be manipulated by the functions of the zoo package.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(dataframe)
```